# How to parse JSON to receive a Date object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, datetime

I have a following piece of JSON:

```
\/Date(1293034567877)\/
```

which is a result of this .NET code:

```
var obj = DateTime.Now;
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.Serialize(obj).Dump();
```

Now the problem I am facing is how to create a Date object from this in JavaScript.
All I could find was incredible regex solution (many containing bugs).

It is hard to believe there is no elegant solution as this is all in JavaScrip, I mean JavaScript code trying to read JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) which is supposed to be a JavaScript code and at this moment it turns out it's not cause JavaScript cannot do a good job here.

I've also seen some eval solutions which I could not make to work (besides being pointed out as security threat).

Is there really no way to do it in an elegant way?

Similar question with no real answer:
[How to parse ASP.NET JSON Date format with GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367899/how-to-parse-asp-net-json-date-format-with-gwt)

Comment: You can just pass the timestamp to the client and call `new Date()` on it.

Comment: If I had timestamp I could, but I have JSON which JavaScript apparently does not understand [sic!]

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There is no standard JSON representation of dates.  You should do what @jAndy suggested and not serialize a `DateTime` at all; just send an RFC 1123 date string `ToString("r")` or a seconds-from-Unix-epoch number, or something else that you can use in the JavaScript to construct a `Date`.

Comment: Thanks I was going down a dead path, you were the first to point out that JSON does not support Date type.

Comment: JSON supports numbers, strings, objects, arrays, and the literals true, false, and null. Since Date is none of those, it is a complex type which should be stored as an object, rather than a string, so you can include type information such as the type name in special members like "$type" that would never resolve to a real object member. Such meta-members can be used to revive the JSON object to a strongly-typed runtime object later. I think the practice of sticking a date in a string is stupid, because it unnecessarily creates reserved string patterns and tries to match them on every string.

Comment: There is now a standard JSON date format.   https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7493#section-4.3

Answer (score 166):

The [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function accepts an optional DateTime reviver function.  You can use a function like this:

```
dateTimeReviver = function (key, value) {
    var a;
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        a = /\/Date\((\d*)\)\//.exec(value);
        if (a) {
            return new Date(+a[1]);
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Then call

```
JSON.parse(somejsonstring, dateTimeReviver);
```

And your dates will come out right.

Comment: This practice of encoding non-primitive typed data in a primitive type (string) is insane.  Encode dates in a JSON object with meaningful properties, or to go even further, include a "$type" property in the JSON object so that the parse/deserialize routine can revive the type appropriately and even use custom converters if you want to pack all the information into a single property value like "ticks" or "ms_since_epoch".

Comment: I had to modify the regex like this /\/Date\((-?\d*)\)\// so that it would be able to handle negative numbers as well.  Negative numbers appear when you have a very old DateTime (before the Epoch) that was converted by .NET to JSON.

Comment: @ClearCloud8: You miss back slashes: /\/Date\\((-?\d*)\\)\//

Comment: Why not `a = Date.parse(value)` instead of `/\/Date\((\d*)\)\//.exec(value);`?

Answer (score 52):

This answer from [Roy Tinker here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-json-date/2316066#2316066):

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```

As he says: *The substr function takes out the "/Date(" part, and the parseInt function gets the integer and ignores the ")/" at the end. The resulting number is passed into the Date constructor.*

Another option is to simply format your information properly on the ASP side such that JavaScript can easily read it. Consider doing this for your dates:

```
DateTime.Now()
```

Which should return a format like this:

```
7/22/2008 12:11:04 PM
```

If you pass this into a JavaScript `Date` constructor like this:

```
var date = new Date('7/22/2008 12:11:04 PM');
```

The variable `date` now holds this value:

```
Tue Jul 22 2008 12:11:04 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

Naturally, you can format this `DateTime` object into whatever sort of string/int the JS `Date` constructor accepts.

Comment: Thanks treeface, this answer helped me out with something recently!

Comment: Never, ever, rely on default date<->string conversion formats. Using milliseconds since Epoch, which stays in the numeric-types domain, is far more simple and reliable.

Comment: This answer presents two solutions - the first one is correct (the parseInt) and the second one wrong, so not sure whether to upvote or downvote! The problem with simply outputting as a string is the date can easily flip backwards if the server is in one country eg US and the browser in another eg UK.

Comment: The first answer to give me any kind of clue

Comment: An OK answer until "*Consider doing this for your dates…*". Suggesting a non–standard format that introduces implementation dependent parsing and timezone issues is not a good idea. The OP format is preferable (though not ideal).

Answer (score 36):

If you use the JavaScript style ISO-8601 date in JSON, you could use this, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON):

```
const jsonDate = (new Date()).toJSON();
const backToDate = new Date(jsonDate);
console.log(jsonDate); //2015-10-26T07:46:36.611Z
```

To create an [ISO-8601 date string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString):

```
myDate.toISOString()
```

Comment: imo this is the most elegant answer and should be the accepted one.

Comment: Very elegant indeed, but this does not relate to the specific date format that was mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 11):

You can convert JSON Date to normal date format in JavaScript.

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with:

```
new Date(1293034567877);
```

This returns for me "Wed Dec 22 2010 16:16:07 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)".

Or do you need to get the number out the json?

Comment: What is wrong with your solution? Well the 1293034567877 is not the JSON I have, right? Also I don't need to get the number out the JSON, I need to get the Date out the JSON. I'm expecting a little bit more from JavaScript than just being able to to everything with regex. I need my code to be readable and not look like a cartoon curse.

Comment: I'd blame .NET for producing a serialization of a date object in a format as weird as `\/Date(1293034567877)\/`. If it was sane, it would just output epoch time and you could initialize a Date object with that.

Comment: I did this like Psytronic offers. The matter is that this is not JSON date, this is .NET date. It is not a great problem to parse a number out of the string, is it?

Comment: @David Dorward: that might be true, what would be a valid JSON in this case?

Comment: JSON doesn't have a Data data type. As I said, I would just use the epoch time, as a Number. `{ date: 1293034567877 }`. Then you could inflate it into a Date object in JS, `foo.date = new Date(foo.date);`

Comment: @David Dorward: I just learned that from google. What a huge mistake in JSON!

Comment: A Number is all you need to represent a date in JSON. There benefits brought by an extra data type wouldn't outweigh the costs of the added complexity.

Comment: @Piotr "A huge mistake" it is not. You can represent a Date as a number or string in multiple ways that make sense to nearly all languages, including epoch time or the UNIX timestamp.

Comment: @treeface: well if you consider the fact that JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation it becomes obvious that someone made a mistake, either naming this thing or forgetting to include the Date type.

Comment: @Piotr But JavaScript Object Notation isn't JavaScript, it is simply a syntax convention taken largely from JavaScript. What point would there be to include a `Date` type when it can be represented as a `String`?

Comment: @treeface: If JSON is not JavaScript then I think tutorials and books are to be blamed for this common misunderstanding. Anyway I gladly stand corrected, really. As for your suggestion that Date can be represented as String I can say that everything can be represented as String, right? But this would not make our job easier, but terribly painfull and hellish. I guess my problem stems from the fact that I considered JSON as a serialization format (advertised to take less bandwidth and work better with JavaScript than XML). As it turns out it's not, at least not a painless one.

Comment: @treeface: I did google your claim about JSON and found out that JSON is JavaScript, actually it is a subset of JavaScript. See RFC #4627 "The application/json Media Type for JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)" and look for a statement: "JSON's design goals were for it to be minimal, portable, textual, and a subset of JavaScript.". Now when I think about it, it seems obvious as you can call eval() on JSON.

Comment: @David Dorward: I would rather have the added complexity be implemented deep inside libraries (either .NET, Java, Ruby, Python, or whatevery language/platform you are on) rather than left the detail to be handled by programmer. Also note that you don't need boolean and integer data types support in JSON, you can just put them in strings, right? Can you imagine how awfull that would be to get anythong from JSON then?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old thread but I wish to post this to help those who bump into this like I did.

if you don't care about using a 3rd party script, you can use [moment,js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/)
Then you can use .format() to format it to anything you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

Dates are always a nightmare. Answering your old question, perhaps this is the most elegant way:

```
eval(("new " + "/Date(1455418800000)/").replace(/\//g,""))
```

With eval we convert our string to javascript code. Then we remove the "/", into the replace function is a regular expression. As we start with new then our sentences will excecute this:

```
new Date(1455418800000)
```

Now, one thing I started using long time ago, is long values that are represented in ticks... why? well, localization and stop thinking in how is date configured in every server or every client. In fact, I use it too in databases.

Perhaps is quite late for this answer, but can help anybody arround here.

Comment: Btw, my english with years is getting worst than ever... but I guess I made my self understood.

Comment: Your answer works great, helped me out of a jam.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS couldn't parse .NET JSON date `/Date(xxxxxxxxxxxxx)/` string either..

I side stepped this issue by formatting the date to its ISO 8601 string representation instead of dumping the `Date` object directly...

Here is a sample of ASP.NET MVC code..

```
return Json(new { 
  date : DateTime.Now.ToString("O") //ISO 8601 Angular understands this format
});
```

I tried `RFC 1123` but  it doesn't work.. Angular treats this as string instead of Date.

```
return Json(new { 
  date : DateTime.Now.ToString("R") //RFC 1123 Angular won't parse this
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not used .Net for things like this. If you were able to get it to print something like the following out it should work.

Note, unless you're parsing that JSON *string* by some other means or only expect users to have modern browers with a built in JSON parser you need to use a JS framework or JSON2 to parse the JSON string outputted by the server into a real JSON object.

```
// JSON received from server is in string format
var jsonString = '{"date":1251877601000}';

//use JSON2 or some JS library to parse the string
var jsonObject =  JSON.parse( jsonString );

//now you have your date!
alert( new Date(jsonObject.date) );
```

---

[Wiki Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

> Modern browsers, such as Firefox 3.5 and Internet Explorer 8, include special features for parsing JSON. As native browser support is more efficient and secure than eval(), it is expected that native JSON support will be included in the next ECMAScript standard.[6]

---

[Link to JSON2 file](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

[Live Example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/BjAyZ/)

Comment: I get it, but my issue with JSON and Date type is that I need to explicitly do "new Date(" which is a) extra work b) additional piece of knowledge that needs to be communicated to the consumer. I am really disappointed to find out how this is handled and I basicaly consider it a mistake in JSON spec.

Comment: the whole web "development" world is basically a big shameless scam. they havent progressed since java script was introduced in 1995.. all web "developers" are cavemen. and they shoot everything which endangers their ecosystem. ie all innovations and innovators.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is, use nuget to obtain JSON.NET then use this inside your `JsonResult` method:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(/* JSON OBJECT TO SEND TO VIEW */);
```

inside your view simple do this in `javascript`:

```
JSON.parse(/* Converted JSON object */)
```

If it is an ajax call:

```
var request = $.ajax({ url: "@Url.Action("SomeAjaxAction", "SomeController")", dataType: "json"});
request.done(function (data, result) { var safe = JSON.parse(data); var date = new Date(safe.date); });
```

Once `JSON.parse` has been called, you can put the JSON date into a `new Date` instance because `JsonConvert` creates a proper ISO time instance

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseJsonDate(jsonDate) {

    var fullDate = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
    var twoDigitMonth = (fullDate.getMonth() + 1) + ""; if (twoDigitMonth.length == 1) twoDigitMonth = "0" + twoDigitMonth;

    var twoDigitDate = fullDate.getDate() + ""; if (twoDigitDate.length == 1) twoDigitDate = "0" + twoDigitDate;
    var currentDate = twoDigitMonth + "/" + twoDigitDate + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear();

    return currentDate;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As Callum mentioned, for me, the best way is to change the Controller method to     string instead of JsonResult".

```
public string GetValues()
{
  MyObject.DateFrom = DateTime.Now;
  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject);
}
```

From the ajax method you can do something like this

```
 $.ajax({
 url: "/MyController/GetValues",
 type: "post",
 success: function (data) {
 var validData = JSON.parse(data);
//if you are using datepicker and you want set a format
$("#DateFrom").val($.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", new Date(validData.DateFrom)));                                      
// if you want the date as returned
$("#DateFrom").val(new Date(validData.DateFrom))
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using eval function works just have to remove the forward slash at front and back.

```
var date1 = "/Date(25200000)/"
eval("new " + date1.substring(1, date1.length - 1));
```

yields Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue with external API providing dates in this format, some times even with UTC difference info like `/Date(123232313131+1000)/`. I was able to turn it js `Date` object with following code

```
var val = '/Date(123232311-1000)/';
var pattern = /^\/Date\([0-9]+((\+|\-)[0-9]+)?\)\/$/;
var date = null;

// Check that the value matches /Date(123232311-1000)/ format
if (pattern.test(val)) {
  var number = val.replace('/Date(', '',).replace(')/', '');
  if (number.indexOf('+') >= 0) {
    var split = number.split('+');
    number = parseInt(split[0]) + parseInt(split[1]);
  } else if (number.indexOf('-') >= 0) {
    var split = number.split('-');
    number = parseInt(split[0]) - parseInt(split[1]);
  } else {
    number = parseInt(number);
    date = new Date(number);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like @jacob have said here [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14509447/17267100) , the reviver param in the JSON.parse could be a good soluction :)

I tried something like this and i receive a good result

```js
function dateTimeReviver(key: string, value: any) {
    if (typeof value === 'string' && /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z$/.test(value)) {
        return new Date(value);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

```
//
// formats a .net date into a javascript compatible date
//
function FormatJsonDate(jsonDt) 
{              
    var MIN_DATE = -62135578800000; // const

    var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDt.substr(6, jsonDt.length-8)));                                                       
    return date.toString() == new Date(MIN_DATE).toString() ? "" : (date.getMonth() + 1) + "\\" + date.getDate() + "\\" + date.getFullYear(); 
}
```

Comment: You're not returning a date object, as far as I understand the code.

Answer (score -1):

```
function parseJsonDate(jsonDate) {

    var fullDate = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
    var twoDigitMonth = (fullDate.getMonth() + 1) + ""; if (twoDigitMonth.length == 1) twoDigitMonth = "0" + twoDigitMonth;

    var twoDigitDate = fullDate.getDate() + ""; if (twoDigitDate.length == 1) twoDigitDate = "0" + twoDigitDate;
    var currentDate = twoDigitMonth + "/" + twoDigitDate + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear();

    return currentDate;
};
```

//Use this function

```
var objDate=parseJsonDate("\/Date(1443812400000)\/");
alert(objDate);
```