# Why does JSON.stringify screw up my datetime object?

Tags: javascript, string, json, node.js

```
{ id: 1533,
  story_type_id: 1,
  content_id: 470,
  created_at: Sun, 05 Feb 2012 07:02:43 GMT,
  updated_at: Sun, 05 Feb 2012 07:02:43 GMT,
  type_name: 'post' }
```

I have a JSON object with the "datetime" field like above.  It's perfect.  But when I stringify it (I want to store it in cache), I get this format:

```
"created_at":"2012-02-05T07:02:43.000Z"
```

This causes problems, because when I want to JSON.parse this, suddenly it's no longer datetime format and it's incompatible with my other format.

What can I do to solve this problem? I have 'created_at' littered everywhere throughout my application. I don't want to manually change each one.

Comment: Presumably you're serialising these dates to store them in localStorage. In that case, you can avoid aggro like this and similar by using a wrapper library like rhaboo.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is not special way to serialize `Date` objects in JSON. That's why you get the standardized string representation. You need to convert them back to `Date` objects by passing them to the `Date` constructor.

```
item['created_at'] = new Date(item['created_at']);
```

Update: With the `reviver` function (see comments), you can get the `Date` objects back.

```
var item = JSON.parse(row, function (key, value) {
  if (key === 'created_at') {
    return new Date(value);
  } else {
    return value;
  }
});
```

Comment: So there's nothing I can do about it?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You would have to store it some other way.

Comment: The `Date` object is native to JavaScript, but JSON is a serialization mechanism used to transport data between platforms. If it allowed serialization of native objects and functions, systems which transmit JSON from JS to, say, PHP would break. You may want to look into the JSON `reviver` methodologies.

Comment: @JanKuča what if I store it like that, but during retrieval, I iterate through each key and check if it's a date. If so, apply new Date() to it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194576/how-do-i-determine-if-a-string-is-date-format

Comment: @JanKuča , what if I don't know the "created_at" part? I have so many  like that...I don't know the key name. I'll have to use regex to check if it's a date or not.

Comment: Yes, you would have to check the value agains a `RegExp` along the lines of `/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+Z$/`

Comment: can I try{ result[k] = new Date(result[k]) }catch(){};  (blank catch statement)

Comment: That does not work. No error is thrown. Try `var date = new Date(value); value = isNaN(date.getTime()) ? date : value;`

Answer (score 18):

It is actually possible to modify how a Date object will be serialized into JSON. Combined with the reviver function, a bi-directional solution can be created which will automatically work on serialization and can easily be used on deserialization.

First modify the serialization like this:

```
Date.prototype.toJSON = function() { return "{timestamp}+" . this.getTime() }
```

This will change the representation of a Date object into a UNIX timestamp with a prefix as a marker:

```
> json = JSON.stringify({test:new Date()});
"{"test":"{timestamp}1380164268633"}"
```

Then you can create a reviver function which will automatically filter out these values:

```
function json_deserialize_helper(key,value) {
  if ( typeof value === 'string' ) {
    var regexp;
    regexp = /^{timestamp}(\d*)$/.exec(value);
    if ( regexp ) {
      return new Date(+regexp[1]);
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```

(Credit: This code was basically copied from this answer in a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14509447/2572897)

Now with this setup, deserialization of our result from before will result in a Date object again:

```
> JSON.parse(json, json_deserialize_helper);
Object {test: Thu Sep 26 2013 04:57:48 GMT+0200 (CEST)}
```

Or you can choose not to modify the serialization but instead use the regexp to catch the standard serialization format:

```
function json_deserialize_helper(key,value) {
  if ( typeof value === 'string' ) {
    var regexp;
    regexp = /^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\dZ$/.exec(value);
    if ( regexp ) {
      return new Date(value);
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```

Example:

```
> json = JSON.stringify({test:new Date()})
"{"test":"2013-09-26T03:05:26.563Z"}"
> JSON.parse(json, json_deserialize_helper)
Object {test: Thu Sep 26 2013 05:05:26 GMT+0200 (CEST)}
```

Comment: this is really depend on the field name. What if there is a lot of fields that must be in Date instance? Handle all fields in the reviever function? Or is there any regex expression that can detect date format?

Comment: It does not depend on the field name. Check the code again. There is a regexp. You might have confused this with another answer which actually depends on a field name.

Comment: You sir are a life saver. Also this solution has to be complemented with the `this` qualifier for the reasons mentioned by @grimace-of-despair in the comments section for the https://stackoverflow.com/a/54037861/5540769

please find revised versions of the replacer and reviver in the following comments.

Comment: ```
const jsonStrigifyDateHelper = function (this: any, key: any, value: any) {
  if (this[key] instanceof Date) {
    return `{timestamp}${getUnixTime(this[key])}`;
  }
  return value;
};
```

Comment: ```

const jsonParseDateHelper = function (this: any, key: any, value: any) {
  if (typeof this[key] === 'string') {
    var regexp;
    regexp = /^{timestamp}(\d*)$/.exec(this[key]);
    if (regexp) {
      return fromUnixTime(parseInt(regexp[1]));
    }
  }
  return value;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);//Mon Jun 11 2018 10:14:33 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)
var json = JSON.stringify(date);
console.log(json);//"2018-06-11T05:44:33.590Z"
var dateStr = JSON.parse(json);  
console.log(dateStr);//2018-06-11T05:44:33.590Z
var date = new Date(dateStr);
console.log(date);//Mon Jun 11 2018 10:14:33 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)
```

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jan/06/JavaScript-JSON-Date-Parsing-and-real-Dates

Answer (score 1):

Date.prototype.toJSON = function() { return moment(this).format('L'); }

You can read more about moment documentation and tailor type of date you want to return.