# How do I determine if a string is date format?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, datetime, date

I have some strings like this: `2012-02-05T07:42:47.000Z` mixed with other strings.  It is **always** in this format. (but the numbers are not the same, of course...the times are different)
(not `Sun, 05 Feb 2012 07:42:47 GMT`)

I want to know whether a string matches that format. How can I determine that?  It's so complicated with the colons and dots and stuff.

Comment: Isn't there are way to parse it directly into Java without a regex?
With a regex you know IF it is a date but if you need also the value I should check on some date parser function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}Z`

Answer (score 0):

The ones for which `!isNaN(+new Date(s))`?

Comment: Just the condensed black magic for "this string is accepted by built-in Date as a date string".

Answer (score 0):

Try matching with the following regular expression:

```
var pattern = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}Z/;
var d = "2012-02-05T07:42:47.000Z";
if(d.match(pattern) !== null){
    //success
} else {
    //failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Date.parse( your_string ) and check the result. This will check any allowed date format, unlike regex.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp
Just realized your string is always in a given format, still unlike regex that function will check if day/month/year are correct etc. So maybe carry 2 checks: 1st to check string format, 2nd to check if numbers are right.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all numbers with a # sign so that "2012-02-05T07:42:47.000Z" looks like "####-##-##T##:##:##.###Z" then you can do a direct string search.

I used this technique to find social security numbers within a large block of document text, I converted all numbers to # signs I just needed to look for strings that were ###-##-####

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you could use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to do this.

```
var check1 = "2012-02-05T07:42:47.000Z";
alert(moment(check1));
//Sat Feb 04 2012 23:42:47 GMT-0800

var check2 = "201-02-05T07:42:47.000Z";
alert(moment(check2));
//Invalid date
```

Play around with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/KFjZF/