# How do I overwride "getTime()" in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

In my app.js (my main file), I want to override getTime();

So now, when I call `created_at.getTime()` in all of my node.js failes that stem from app.js via requires, they should use this new **getTime()** function that I just overrided.

Basically, I want to change the entire getTime() function to my own, throughout my entire project.

Comment: What is created_at? A Date object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `Date.prototype.getTime` but **DO NOT DO THAT** as it will break many libraries you would ever use.

You can use the same trick as with `JSON.parse`:

```
var serialized = JSON.stringify(obj, function (key, value) {
    if (value instanceof Date) {
      return dateHandler(value);
    } else {
      return value;
    }
});
```

You would define the `dateHandler` function.

> To keep others in the loop, I'm referring to [OP's previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194372/why-does-json-stringify-screw-up-my-datetime-object).