# Object.prototype.toString.call(currentFruit) === "[object Date]"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I am new to js.
I have an `if` condition that I did not understand.
Can you tell me what this if condition does?

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(currentFruit) === "[object Date]"
```

Can you explain it?
Providing my code below:

```
setcurrentFruit: function (fruitName, currentFruit) {
    WorklistStorage.set(fruitName, currentFruit, false);
},
getcurrentFruit: function (fruitName) {
    var currentFruit = unescapeJSON(WorklistStorage.get(fruitName, false));
    if (currentFruit == "undefined" || typeof currentFruit == "undefined" || Object.prototype.toString.call(currentFruit) === "[object Date]") {
        var date = new Date();
        currentFruit = date.toString();
        wholeQueue.setcurrentFruit(fruitName, currentFruit);
        //console.log("poppppp");
    }
    currentFruit = new Date(currentFruit);
    return currentFruit;
},
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's break it down;

- [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object); the reference for native *JavaScript Objects*.
- [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype); the reference to properties inherited by all instances of *Object*.
- [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString); the native `toString` method of all *Objects*.
- [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call); a method to invoke a *function* with a chosen [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

So `Object.prototype.toString.call(currentFruit)` is invoking the native `toString` of all *Objects* on `currentFruit`. This might be different to `currentFruit.toString()` if there is another `toString` defined on or inherited by `currentFruit`.

`Object.prototype.toString` returns a *String* of the form `[object X]` where `X` is the *type* of `this`, so comparing against `[object Date]` with `===` is asking *"Is `currentFruit` a *Date*?"*

Why is doing this check more useful than [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)? Because `typeof` will often just return `"object"`, which is not often helpful.

What about [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)? This will be `true` if the thing you're checking inherits from what you're testing against as well, so for example, `x instanceof Object` is usually `true`, which is not always helpful either.

An alternate method you could think of as similar would be to test the *constructor* of an *Object*. `x.constructor === Date`. This has a different set of problems, such as `throw`ing errors if `x` is *undefined* or *null* so needs more checks etc. but it can be more helpful if you're working with non-native constructors, for which `toString` would simply give `[object Object]`.

---

All this said, you need to consider whether this test will ever be true given the environment you're working with. Currently there is no standard *JSON* representation of a *Date*.

Answer (score 1):

[`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is used to get the internal [[Class]] value of javascript objects. In here, it tests whether `currentFruit` is a native [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

It could easily be replaced by [`currentFruit instanceof Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) (though there are minor differences).

Comment: Because currentFruit is parsed JSON you can't check instanceof: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511705/how-to-parse-json-to-receive-a-date-object-in-javascript seems that Date doesn't exist in JSON `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Date())) instanceof Date===false`

Comment: @HMR: I had expected as well that the test hardly makes sense, but notice that OP is doing `unescapeJSON` (probably with some magic) not `JSON.parse`.