# Parsing JSON with a Javascript Date object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, api, parsing

I am using a SOAP API that returns XML but with JSON strings within the response envelope. For most of the API calls this has not been a problem but there is one that returns Javascript `new Date` objects that is causing problems when using `JSON.parse`. Here is a simplified example of the response I am getting.

`"{\"History\":[ {\"Timestamp\":new Date(1380024020923)}]}"`

When using `JSON.parse` I get the following error.

`JSON::ParserError: 399: unexpected token at '{"Timestamp":new Date(1380024020923)}]}'`

Is there a nice way to parse this string or am I going to have to use some regex/string trickery? Has anyone come across this way of returning a date object and I would like to understand the advantage?

Comment: See this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511705/how-to-parse-json-to-receive-a-date-object-in-javascript) and look for the answer with dateTimeReviver.With a change in the regex, that should work for you.

Comment: That's not [JSON](http://json.org), that's a chunk of JavaScript source code. No, they're not the same thing.

Comment: @Pete thanks +1 for the link, what I understand from that is ideally the api would return the date as a string but in this case I will have to regex them, convert the dates to strings and then parse it as JSON to enable me to use it. Would you consider this an API bug?

Comment: No, not a bug. It's simply a results of JSON standard not having a defined date format, so different vendors and users have created their own ways of passing dates. So not a bug, just an incomplete standard, in my mind...