# c# JSON date issue

Tags: c#, jquery, json, jquery-templates

I have a date in my DB  of 2014-03-03 05:00:00, which is being rendered in JSON as:

[image]

the date is /Date{(-6xxxxx)/ and I call this method to parse it:

```
   function parseJsonDate(dateString) {
      var result = new Date(+dateString.replace(/\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\//gi, "$1"));
      var result = new Date(parseInt(dateString.replace('/Date(', '')));
      result.format("dd-MM-yyyy");
      return result;
   }
```

when running, i comment out one of the results lines, but get the same result for both:

[image]

the method is being called from Jquery template like such:

```
<tr>
   <td>
    <span id="approvedDate"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" data-toggle="tooltip" 
        data-original-title="approved date"></i> ${parseJsonDate(AuditDate)}</span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

***EDIT***

What a muppet.. I spent so long thinking this was a JSON vconversion issue, i totally forgot to go back and check my dapper code. my ApprovalHistory objec had AuditDate, but I was asking for EnteredDate in the sql. So, it was doing as expected.

aaaaaaaarrr :-)

Comment: Would it not be simpler to convert the date/time on the server when you get it out of the DB and return it as a formatted string?

Comment: yeah,I've done that, but it is still being returned as such

Comment: You must have done something wrong then because if you format the date/time correctly on the server and then return it as a string, that's what you'll get, not the value shown in the question.

Comment: This thread might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511705/how-to-parse-json-to-receive-a-date-object-in-javascript

Comment: @Archer that's the way c#'s javascript formatter parses DateTime object.

Comment: @Steve - It's not a valid JavaScript date/time value, which is why I suggest he formats it on the server and passes a string.  The whole issue would disappear immediately.  Have you tried converting that value to a date/time?

Comment: @Archer it is pretty obvious that he is using a javascript serializer, and the problem with that is you can't specify how it serializes it. If you want to turn it into a string you would have to make another public string getter and do it that way. But it is one duplicated info in the returned Data. So depending on how perfectionist you are, it is one way to go.

Comment: @CSharpNewBee The problem here is the value you are returning.  Serializing the date you show above, in C# (using JavaScriptSerializer) returns `"\/Date(1393822800000)\/"`.  You can convert that back to a date/time object in Javascript using `new Date(1393822800000)` and that shows the correct date.  The value you are returning is wrong.

Comment: @Steve - Please see the comment I just posted above.  He doesn't need to return it as a date.  He can format it as a string and have a string property in the object he is returning.  That would be much simpler and would fix the problem immediately.

Comment: @Archer um....yea it looks strange to me that he has a negative value as the Date(xxxx). wonder how he did it

Comment: @Steve He says the format is -6xxxx (the xxxx being the date), but it's just not the right value, regardless.  Not sure what's going on here at all.

Comment: @Steve et al, see edit above, whats going on here, is square eye syndrome, and working too many hours :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programmer error, not a code error.

Comment: @Archer, this is a two part question, i still need to know how to get it in dd mm yyyy format.

Comment: That's a simple search and has been answered on SO before... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: thats fine, but at the time, I didn't know right? You're off-topic seems a bit unjust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing something fishy there

```
var result = new Date(+dateString.replace(/\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\//gi, "$1"));
var result = new Date(parseInt(dateString.replace('/Date(', '')));
```

1. you are making two variables named result within the same closure, is it intentional?
2. what does result.format do? since result is a Date object I wouldn't assume that it would change the original type from Date to string.

Maybe

`var s = result.format("dd-MM-yyyy");
 return s;`

is what you really want to do?

you can do this after the ajax complete, this will save you tons of trouble having to parse the Date(xxxxx) thing over and over again

```
data = data.replace(/\"\\\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\\\/\"/g, '$1')
```

this will convert "Date(xxxx)" to xxxx and then you can just call new Date(xxxx) to make new Date object.

Comment: Steve, reread the question. I've left like this for the purpose of what i've tried.

Comment: @CSharpNewBee sorry my bad. But what about the format part

Comment: the format was to try and move away from this:

Mon Mar 03 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use something like this:

```
var str = (result.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + result.getDate() + "-" + result.getFullYear();
return str;
```