# How to parse date field from json using angularJs filter

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Here is what i'm getting from json file `/Date(1435837792000+0000)/`

I need to display date in the following format `Oct 29, 2010 9:10:23 AM`

Comment: Can you add the complete json? = /Date(1435837792000+0000)/ is not valid json.

Comment: this what im getting  "PublishDate": "\/Date(1435757849000+0000)\/"

Comment: @Hannes Johansson i know using angular = {{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}: Oct 29, 2010 9:10:23 AM we can achieve bt value im getting is suppose to be filter out first

Comment: I would say this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511705/how-to-parse-json-to-receive-a-date-object-in-javascript

Comment: Not a duplicate, but interesting anyway: [*The “right” JSON date format*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format).

Comment: @Hannes Johansson  i just wanna know to use angularjs filter here

Comment: @HannesJohansson–not exactly, the OP's format seems to include an offset in some unspecified value (probably hhmm but who knows since the "date" seems to be milliseconds).

Comment: That's not what the title or the question says. Update the question to actually state what you really want to know.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function like format() on the Date prototype in Javascript. But there are these methods:

```
getDate() // Returns the date
getMonth() // Returns the month
getFullYear() // Returns the year
getHours() // Returns the hour
getMinutes() // Returns the minute
getSeconds() // Returns the second
```

You can form the string yourself using:

```
function formatDate(dt) {
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April",
        "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
        "October", "November", "December"];

    var h = dt.getHours(), am;
    if (h > 12) {
        am = 'pm';
        h = h - 12;
    } else {
        am = 'am';
    }

    return monthNames[dt.getMonth()].substring(0, 3) + ' ' +
        dt.getDate() + ', ' + dt.getFullYear() + ' ' +
        h + ':' + dt.getMinutes() + ':' + dt.getSeconds() + ' ' +
        am;
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date(1435837792000+0000)));
```

If you are finding yourselves in need of more date parsing and formatting, check out the [Momentjs](http://momentjs.com) library. With moment, you could just do:

```
moment(new Date(1435837792000+0000)).format("MMM D, YYYY hh:mm:ss A")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract this value from your json.

Assign it to a scope variable in the controller.
yourCtrl.js

```
json = { name: 'stackoverflow',
         date: 1435837792000+0000
       };
$scope.today = new Date(json.date); //This converts the date value from the json to a healthy looking date something like this `2015-07-02T11:49:52.000Z`
```

today.html

```
{{ today | date:'medium' }}
```

This angular filter will display your date in the desired date format.
 Oct 29, 2010 9:10:23 AM

EDIT:

```
$scope.today = Date(1435837792000+0000);
$scope.today = new Date($scope.today);
```

and then pipe it up as using the angular filters as follows

`{{ today | date:'MMM d, y hh:mm:ss' }}` or `{{ today | date:'medium' }}` based upon your requirement.

Comment: after extrating from json im getting   /Date(1435837792000+0000)/

Comment: its not 1435837792000+0000

Comment: Okay. Can you may be post the whole of the json?

Comment: I used console.log(Date(1435837792000+0000)); . The output is Wed Jul 08 2015 12:10:43 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time). Just do: $scope.today = Date(1435837792000+0000); and then use a date filter {{ today | date:'medium' }}

Comment: no json is like this "PublishDate": "\/Date(1435757849000+0000)\/"

Comment: i'm having arrays of object so thats why i need a angular filter

Comment: Okay. Do this. I think this will resolve it. $scope.today = Date(1435837792000+0000);
 $scope.today = new Date($scope.today); and then pipe it up as {{ today | date:'MMM d, y hh:mm:ss' }} or  {{ today | date:'medium' }} based upon your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First get the timestamp from JSON to a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) variable, here’s a brute [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
var json = { "PublishDate": "\/Date(1435757849000+0000)\/" };
var timestamp = parseInt(json.PublishDate.match(/\d+/)[0],10);
var date = new Date(timestamp);
```

Then, a mix of [`.toDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) and [`.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString), both quirky (yet localized) and possibly unreliable non-standard, might come close:

```
date = date.toDateString() + ' ' + date.toLocaleTimeString('en');
alert( date === 'Wed Jul 01 2015 3:37:29 PM' );
```

There’s also [`.toGMTString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString) that returns `Thu, 02 Jul 2015 11:49:52 GMT` (RFC 1123) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Use JS to convert it to Date object & then date function on it..

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function jsonDatetoJSDate(){
    var dateFromServer = "/Date(1435837792000+0000)/";
    //Javascript conversion
    var prsdDt = new Date(parseInt(dateFromServer.substr(6)));
    //getting Date Object
    var uDate = new Date(prsdDt);
    alert(uDate);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:jsonDatetoJSDate()">
    Use Date Function on javaScript
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in comments, if the JSON you are getting is something like

```
var obj = {
              "PublishDate": "\/Date(1435757849000+0000)\/"
          }
```

and you have no control in changing the value(since you are enclosing the Date() around slashes), then you would need to

- escape the slashs around `Date`.

  ```
    obj.PublishDate.replace(/\//g, "");
  ```
- and evaluate the remaining expression

  ```
    eval(obj.PublishDate.replace(/\//g, ""))
  ```

to get the actual Date: `Wed Jul 08 2015 11:48`