# What format for dates does jQuery.ajax() expect JSON datatype

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, json-deserialization

Strange that I can't find an answer to this one...

Simply, what date format (if any) will a call using [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) deserialize properties into javascript dates?

ISO 8601 doesn't seem to work. The following: `2015-10-21T23:44:21.292Z` and `2015-10-21T23:44:21Z` both fail.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/trees/leopardTree-01',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (tree) {
    if (tree.PlantingDate instanceof Date) {
      //YAY I know when my tree was planted
    }
  }
});
```

I want to know when my tree was planted.

**Update on duplicate**

It's not quite the same question as [The “right” JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format). Although that question is informative, if a little philisophical (e.g. what is the right colour for a flower to be?). I'm interested in a solution to automatically parse a string into a datetime object, using a framework, in this case jQuery. This could be via a custom formatter as per @Neverever's comment (e.g. pick me only blue flowers). I'm surprised jQuery doesn't offer this sort of thing as an option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The "right" JSON date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format)

Comment: this answer might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14509447/381709

Comment: @Neverever that's the sort of thing I was looking for. I suppose I'll have to manually parse the JSON. Just flabberghasted that jQuery ajax doesn't support custom formatters / reviver functions.

Answer (score 0):

JSON itself does not have a standard representation for datetime. This implies that Ajax can not parse dates automatically, you have to do it yourself:

Example (when `tree.PlantingDate` in ISO 8601 format):

```
success: function (tree) {
  var plantingDate = new Date(tree.PlantingDate);

  if (!isNaN(plantingDate)) {
    //YAY I know when my tree was planted
  }
}
```