# How to get Date object from json Response in typescript

Tags: json, typescript, angular

Here is my json:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "comment": "3541",
      "datetime": "2016-01-01"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is model:

```
export class Job {
    constructor(comment:string, datetime:Date) {
        this.comment = comment;
        this.datetime = datetime;
    }

    comment:string;
    datetime:Date;
}
```

Query:

```
getJobs() {
        return this._http.get(jobsUrl)
            .map((response:Response) => <Job[]>response.json().data)
}
```

Problem is that after casting to `Job[]` i expect `datetime`property to be `Date` but it is string. Shouldn't it cast to Date object? What am i missing here?

Comment: Seems to be a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511705/how-to-parse-json-to-receive-a-date-object-in-javascript

Comment: Read that one, doesnt really answers my question about TS

Answer (score 26, accepted):

@Gunter is absolutely correct. The only thing I would like to add is actually how to deserialize json object keeping its date properties as dates and not strings (from the referenced post its not that easy to see this approach).

Here is my attempt:

```
export class Helper
{
    public static Deserialize(data: string): any
    {
        return JSON.parse(data, Helper.ReviveDateTime);
    }

    private static ReviveDateTime(key: any, value: any): any 
    {
        if (typeof value === 'string')
        {
            let a = /\/Date\((\d*)\)\//.exec(value);
            if (a)
            {
                return new Date(+a[1]);
            }
        }
 
        return value;
    }
}
```

You can see this approach for example here: [JSON.parse Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc836466(v=vs.94).aspx) in the dateReviver example.

Comment: In my case, as I was simply receiving a string like `2018-12-06T15:32:43.590`, my function just assigns `new Date(value)` to a variable and then checks its status before returning.

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to know for TS/JS that this value is a date. It's a string and treated as such. Other data types are distinguishable but JSON doesn't provide any special support for date. You need to convert it manually.

See for example this discussion how to transport and convert a date using JSON [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/format-a-microsoft-json-date)

Comment: Thats strange, isnt it? if ``Job`` object has ``datetime`` property as ``Date`` and im casting to Job, doesn't that mean that i want to cast all properties correspondingly.

Comment: I don't know TS too well but I don't think you can cast a string to a date, you would need to convert it instead. At runtime it's quite meaningless that you cast to `Job` at all.

Answer (score 0):

If usage of custom TypeScript transformer is possible, [ts-transformer-dates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-transformer-dates) could be used:

```
import { toDates } from 'ts-transformer-dates';

const value = {
  "data": [
    {
      "comment": "3541",
      "datetime": "2016-01-01"
    }
  ]
};

export class Job {
    constructor(comment:string, datetime:Date) {
        this.comment = comment;
        this.datetime = datetime;
    }

    comment:string;
    datetime:Date;
}

console.log(toDates<{data:Job[]}>(value));
```

Output:

```js
{ data: [ { comment: '3541', datetime: 2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using 2 properties: a string property (say dateStr) for passing the date and a Date property (say dateVal) to hold the data object after conversion.

Then in your constructor, you can simply do something like `dateVal = new Date(dateStr)`.