# Date object being treated as string in template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to use Angular2 date pipe to format a date. I have this class as model for my object:

```
export class Match {
    Id: number;
    MatchDate: Date;

    constructor(
        id: number,
        matchDate: Date
) {
        this.Id = id;
        this.MatchDate = matchDate;
    }
}
```

And I fetch Match objects to my Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Match} from '../core/models/match';
import {MatchService} from '../core/services/match.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './app/components/home.html',
    directives: [],
    providers:[MatchService]
})

export class Home implements OnInit {
    nextMatch: Match;
    lastMatch: Match;
    errorMessage: string;


    constructor(
        private _matchService: MatchService
    ) { }

    getNextMatch() {
        this._matchService.getNextMatch()
            .subscribe(
            nextMatch => this.nextMatch = nextMatch,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }

    getLastMatch() {
        this._matchService.getLastMatch()
            .subscribe(
            lastMatch => this.lastMatch = lastMatch,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getNextMatch();
        this.getLastMatch();
    }
}
```

In my template I try to display the MatchDate:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div *ngIf="lastMatch" class="card">
            <div class="card__content">
                <p>{{lastMatch.MatchDate | date:"short"}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div *ngIf="nextMatch" class="card">
            <div class="card__content">
                <p>{{nextMatch.MatchDate}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When using `{{nextMatch.MatchDate}}` I get the correct date, but not formatted as I want. If I use `{{lastMatch.MatchDate | date:"short"}}` I get an error saying:

> Invalid argument '2016-02-01T18:30:00' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Shouldn't MatchDate be a Date object, not a string?

EDIT:

Here's part of my MatchService:

```
getNextMatch() {
    return this.http.get(this._apiUrl + '/next')
        .map(res => <Match>res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: How does your `_matchService` retrieve dates? If it's from an HTTP request, do you convert them as dates?

Comment: Your MatchService needs to return JavaScript Date objects.  I assume it is returning strings.

Comment: I've added the code from my MatchService. I thought it would also map to the correct types, when doing this map.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't convert values to the appropriate/declared types.

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3261 and this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6336#issuecomment-173562587)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your service doesn't return dates. If you get dates from an HTTP request, there is no native support to get date from the response since the JSON format doesn't provide support for date.

See this question for more details:

- [How to get Date object from json Response in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917808/how-to-get-date-object-from-json-response-in-typescript/35923990#35923990)