# Angular 2 Date deserialization

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I have an Angular 2 application.  A service is requests data from an api that returns the results like the following:

```
{
    "data":[
        {"id":1,"timestamp":"2016-04-17T19:52:53.4510935+01:00","sourceDatabaseServer":"127.0.0.1","sourceDatabaseName":"Database1","targetDatabaseServer":"192.168.99.101","targetDatabaseName":"Database2"},
        {"id":2,"timestamp":"2016-04-17T19:52:53.4510935+01:00","sourceDatabaseServer":"127.0.0.2","sourceDatabaseName":"Database3","targetDatabaseServer":"192.168.99.102","targetDatabaseName":"Database4"},
        {"id":3,"timestamp":"2016-04-17T19:52:53.4510935+01:00","sourceDatabaseServer":"127.0.0.3","sourceDatabaseName":"Database5","targetDatabaseServer":"192.168.99.103","targetDatabaseName":"Database6"}
    ]
}
```

My Angular 2 service looks like this (I've cut the error handling for brevity as we're on the happy path here):

```
getList() : Observable<SomeModel[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._getListUrl).map(this.extractData);
}

 private extractData(res: Response) {
    return res.json().data || {};
}
```

and my component like this:

```
results: SomeModel[];
errorMessage: string;
ngOnInit() {
    this._someService.getList()
        .subscribe(
        results => this.results = results, 
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

and my model like this:

```
export class SomeModel {

    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public timestamp: Date,
        public sourceDatabaseServer: string,
        public sourceDatabaseName: string,
        public targetDatabaseServer: string,
        public targetDatabaseName: string
    ) { }
}
```

Everything looked like it was working however when I tried to display timestamp using the DatePipe like so `{{item.timestamp | date:'short'}}` the application blows up with the following error message:

```
Invalid argument '2016-04-17T19:40:38.2424240+01:00' for pipe 'DatePipe' in [{{result.timestamp | date:'short'}}
```

After some investigation I believe that timestamp is not actually being converted to the `Date` type but is instead just being set a `string`.  I'm guessing this is becuase the `Date` type isn't known at the time `Response.json()` is called?  or am I missing something else entirely?  Is there a fix or work around for this?

Comment: When you do a `.json()` that will not transform a string (even if it's in some date format) to an actual date object. It'll keep being a string. so you need to do `new Date(herePassTheString)`

Comment: If you are only displaying it, the DatePipe in Angular 2 can now use the ISO string format. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html  I do not know if this has always been the case, but it is now. ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would map the string field to a date one:

```
getList() : Observable<SomeModel[]> {
  return this._http.get(this._getListUrl).map(this.extractData);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
  var data = res.json().data || [];
  data.forEach((d) => {
    d.timestamp = new Date(d.timestamp);
  });
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Yep, best approach...  everything after that is in alignment then!  And here's for an alternative format :-), `d.timestamp = new Date(parseInt(d.timestamp.substr(6)));`

Comment: Why do I get an error on this line: var data = res.json().data || []; when I try to use this code? "Property data does not exist on type Promise<any>"

Answer (score 6):

The `date` pipe only accepts `Date` values not string values.

See [How to get Date object from json Response in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917808/how-to-get-date-object-from-json-response-in-typescript) for how to convert dates in JSON.

Alternatively you can create your own string-to-date conversion pipe

```
@Pipe({name: 'toDate'})
export class StringToDate implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, [exponent]) : number {
    if(value) {
      return new Date(value);
    }
  }
}
```

and then use it like

```
{{item.timestamp |toDate | date:'short'}}
```

Hint: don't forget to add the pipe to `pipes: [StringToDate]` on the `@Component(...)` decorater where you want to use it.

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8038
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7794

Comment: This is actually an angularJS (angular 1) response. Angular 2 now supports a variety of formats, including the correct ISO string format. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html

Comment: It's not a AngularJS 1 answer (don't know 1.x), but it's almost a year old and a lot has changed since then. I'll update when I'm back. Thanks for the note.

Comment: Ah, sorry. You are correct. I see your @Pipe in there now. I was actually confused since the docs for angular 1 were the ref links. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html

Comment: Best resources for this: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

here: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe and here: https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-tips-formatting-dates-with-a-custom-date-pipe-dd-mm-yyyy/

Answer (score 3):

JSON does not provide any date specification, so it is entirely up to how it is serialized/deserialized.

You could use `reviver` parameter of `JSON.parse`:

```
this._http.get(this._getListUrl).map(res => JSON.parse(res.text(), this.reviver));

reviver(key, value):any
{
    if('timestamp' === key){
        //you can use any de-serialization algorithm here
        return new Date(value);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try out my example if its work for you. And here is the docs for [Date](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html) and [Pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html).

```
<span>Date : {{announcement.createdAt | date:'EEE, d MMM,y'}}</span>
<span>Time : {{announcement.createdAt | date:'shortTime'}}</span>
```

**Output :**

```
Date : Tue, 20 Dec,2016    
Time :  2:22 PM
```