# Format kendo-ui-angular2 grid date column using property

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Was wondering if it is possible to format a date in a column using a property.
E.g:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="DOB" format="{0:d}" title="DOB" width="160"  >
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

I would like to format the DOB using a property.
In my TS file I would have something like:

```
shortDate="dd/mm/yyyy"
```

In HTML:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="DOB" format="{0:shortDate}" title="DOB" width="160"  >
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

Something like that possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution I ended up using:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="DOB" title="DOB" width="160" >
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            {{dataItem.DOB | date:config.ShortDate}}
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone in future's use, You can easily format it using below **format** property as below

```
<kendo-grid-column title="Received On" field="labReceivedDate" format="{0: dd MMM yyyy}" width="120px "></kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: The idea was to store the formatiing in an external file, not in the column itself. So that you would only have to change it in in place and not in all columns seperately.