# Angular Kendo UI Grid DateTime format in yyyy/MM/dd from the Epoch time

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, datetime-format, epoch

I am using `Kendo UI Grid` with `Angular 6` and getting data from `API` where datetime is coming in Epoch format like below :

```
x.items[0].EffectiveDate.$date = 1550719967
```

i am using below `html` for kendo grid column and Sort should work as well. I have gone through the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43329796/kendo-angular-2-grid-datetime-format) and [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47661072/grid-date-formating-in-kendo-ui-for-angular) but didn't solved the issue.

If anyone have face this kind of scenario please help me to figure it out.
 Thanks in Advance.

```
<kendo-grid-column field="EffectiveDate" title="Effective Date" filter="date" format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss }" [style]="{'text-align': 'left'}" width="130">
 <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
    {{ dataItem.EffectiveDate?.$date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}
</ng-template> </kendo-grid-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo mistake in

```
x.items[0].EffectiveDate.$date = 15159I4400000
```

this value contains an `I` i.e. `15159'I'4400000`

Try with `1515914400000`

Comment: i have tried like this  {{ dataItem.FirstOrderedOn | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}} and it is showing me 19/01/1970 04:13:55.with every Epoch time it is taking 19/01/1970.with different date format also it is taking 1970.

Comment: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/96WkJnofxjiHV6GmaZjj?p=preview), is having a example where i am trying to change the datasource datetime as epoch time

Comment: Hey @AbhishekKumarSeth I have updated my answer. Please try in this way to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have tried your approach but it was not working.(I have updated my question with correct Epoch time). it was always giving me the 19/01/1970. But now i am able to format it to convert epoch time to date. i am inserting the code snippet in the next answer section.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <kendo-grid-column field="EffectiveDate" title="Effective Date" filter="date" format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss }" [style]="{'text-align': 'left'}"
width="130">
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
  {{ getdateformat(dataItem.EffectiveDate.$date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}
</ng-template>
```

```
getdateformat(utcSeconds){
if (utcSeconds == null || utcSeconds == "" || utcSeconds == undefined){
  return "";
}
var d = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
d.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);
return d;
}
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date) to convert epoch to date