# Angular 4.4 Date deserialization from REST-Service

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 4's new HttpModule to retrieve data from a REST-Service. The problem is, that the data contains a Date typed property. I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681078/angular-2-date-deserialization) but when I try the solution suggested in the thread, I get the following error: `res.json is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
getMarkets(): Observable<Christmasmarket[]> {
    let markets: Christmasmarket[];
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).map(this.extractData);

  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {

    let body = res.json().data;
    console.log(body);
    body.forEach((d) => {
      d.start = new Date(d.start)
      d.end = new Date(d.end);
    });
    return body.data || {};
  }
```

And here is the data from the service:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "mein markt1",
    "start": "2017-11-14T23:00:47.838+0000",
    "end": "2017-12-14T23:00:47.838+0000",
    "postalCode": "1100",
    "city": "wien",
    "address": "test",
    "rating": 4.56,
    "ratingPrice": 1.2,
    "numberOfRatings": 10,
    "latLng": {
      "latitude": 48.208982,
      "longitude": 16.373213
    },
    "openingHours": [
      {
        "open": true,
        "start": 600,
        "end": 1200,
        "dayOfWeek": 0
      },
      {
        "open": true,
        "start": 660,
        "end": 1200,
        "dayOfWeek": 1
      },
      {
        "open": true,
        "start": 690,
        "end": 1200,
        "dayOfWeek": 2
      },
      {
        "open": true,
        "start": 600,
        "end": 1200,
        "dayOfWeek": 3
      },
      {
        "open": true,
        "start": 600,
        "end": 1200,
        "dayOfWeek": 4
      },
      {
        "open": true,
        "start": 600,
        "end": 1200,
        "dayOfWeek": 5
      },
      {
        "open": true,
        "start": 600,
        "end": 1200,
        "dayOfWeek": 6
      }
    ],
    "extraordinaryOpeningHours": [

    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using the new `HttpClientModule`, rather then the old `HttpModule`. With `HttpClient`, the deserialization from JSON is done automatically, so there is no `response.json()` method.

More about it in angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/http

Also note then with `HttpClient`, you can specify interface of the response, so it will automatically map it for you:

```
interface ItemsResponse {
  results: string[];
}

http.get<ItemsResponse>('/api/items').subscribe(data => {
  // data is now an instance of type ItemsResponse, so you can do this:
  this.results = data.results;
});
```

This should work also with `Date` type i guess.

Comment: Yes thank you, I did not quite get it that the extractData now takes my type as a parameter as well. Thanks!

Comment: What you actually missed is that you shouldn't need an extractData method at all - the  HttpClient does that for you.

Comment: @GreyBeadedGekk I tried it without the extractData function and no, it does not work. Somehow it does not map it as a date. When I'm calling start.getTime() I'm getting an error that there is not such a function - because it is a String.