# Kendo UI Angular 2 grid date editor TypeError: date.getTime is not a function

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a grid where I set the column editor as [editor]="'date'" and it's now throwing an error when I try to edit the cell. I get the following error. The json date looks like an ISO format date which I think might be the issue but I don't know how to fix it.

```
{"Date":"2016-12-14T00:00:00"}

ERROR TypeError: date.getTime is not a function
    at Object.exports.cloneDate (clone-date.js:15)
    at DatePickerComponent.writeValue (datepicker.component.js:295)
    at setUpControl (shared.ts:57)
    at FormControlDirective.ngOnChanges (form_control_directive.ts:107)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (provider.ts:276)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (view.ts:519)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (view.ts:462)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (services.ts:389)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (services.ts:476)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (CellComponent.html:17)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to change the Date string to a valid Date object.

If you get if from an api call, you can use Observables to automatically transform that date string. [Angular 2 Date deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681078/angular-2-date-deserialization)

In general you only have to say *new Date('2016-12-14T00:00:00')* to get a valid Date object.
Be aware that your date is missing time zone information. A valid iso string would look like this: 2016-12-14T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: This probably would  be the solution, meaning the linked post, but it doesn't compile for me. I posted in the other post about my problem.

Comment: Why do I get an error on this line: var data = res.json().data || []; when I try to use this code? "Property data does not exist on type Promise<any>"

Answer (score 0):

**For guys who also got this error**

If you have grid like [kendo reactive form example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-reactive-forms/) you can do that:

**ts:**

```
   //form initialization
    const createFormGroup = dataItem => new FormGroup({
  'publicationId': new FormControl(dataItem.publicationId), 
  'publicationDate': new FormControl(new Date(dataItem.publicationDate), Validators.required),
  'authors': new FormControl(dataItem.authors)
});

//new form creating
public createForm() {
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
  'publicationDate': new Date(),
  'authors': new FormControl()
});
}
```

**html:**

```
 <kendo-grid-column field="publicationDate" title="Publication Date" format="{0: dd MMM yyyy}" editor="date" width="160">
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
  {{log(dataItem)}}
 
  {{dataItem.publicationDate | date:ShortDate}}
</ng-template>
```

Hope it will help someone:)