# Where to store Class instance for reusability in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to implement a messaging library Chatkit by Pusher in my React/Redux/redux saga app and I'm new to Redux. The code for connecting to chatkit looks like this:

```
const chatManager = new ChatManager({
    instanceLocator: 'v1:us1:80215247-1df3-4956-8ba8-9744ffd12161',
    userId: 'sarah',
    tokenProvider: new TokenProvider({ url: 'your.auth.url' })
})

chatManager.connect()
    .then(currentUser => {
        console.log('Successful connection', currentUser)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error on connection', err)
    })
```

I need to store the chatManager and currentUser objects, (which are instances of complex classes with functions atttached) globally so that I can use them again later to join rooms, subscribe to events etc.

My first thought was that I should store it in Redux as that's now my "global store" but I then realised that it probably won't work as it won't be the original object I get back out of the store, it'll presumably a clone. I then read that apparently only plain objects are supposed to be stored in Redux.

So, where are things that aren't plain objects but do need to be stored globally? I don't want to put them on the window object as I may convert this to a React Native app and it seems messy anyway.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Per the [Redux FAQ entry on storing "connection"-type objects](https://redux.js.org/faq/codestructure#where-should-websockets-and-other-persistent-connections-live):

> Middleware are the right place for persistent connections like websockets in a Redux app, for several reasons:
>
> - Middleware exist for the lifetime of the application
> - Like with the store itself, you probably only need a single instance of a given connection that the whole app can use
> - Middleware can see all dispatched actions and dispatch actions themselves.  This means a middleware can take dispatched actions and turn those into messages sent over the websocket, and dispatch new actions when a message is received over the websocket.
> - A websocket connection instance isn't serializable, so it doesn't belong in the store state itself​

**edit**

Here's my "sample socket middleware" example, updated to delay creating the socket until it sees a login action:

```
const createMySocketMiddleware = (url) => {
    let socket;

    return storeAPI => next => action => {
        switch(action.type) {
            case "LOGIN" : {
                socket = createMyWebsocket(url);

                socket.on("message", (message) => {
                    storeAPI.dispatch({
                        type : "SOCKET_MESSAGE_RECEIVED",
                        payload : message
                    });
                });
                break;
            }
            case "SEND_WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE": {
                socket.send(action.payload);
                return;
            }
        }

        return next(action);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense I guess. I'm going to have to learn how to make middlewate!

Comment: The FAQ entry links to [a sample socket middleware I wrote](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/3df1cf5abbac57820a20059287b4be58), plus other "real" ones. Besides [the "Middleware" page in the Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware), my [Redux Fundamentals workshop slides have a section on writing middleware too](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/06/redux-fundamentals-workshop-slides/), and I have [links to more articles on middleware here](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-middleware.md).

Comment: Just one more question. The sample instantiates the connector when it is created. In my app the connector isn't created until the user logs in. Would it be possible to create middleware which does nothing until it sees a login action (which is currently handled using redux-saga) and then instantiates the connector and deals with other chat related actions from that point onwards? I assum all middleware has to be applied from the beginning, it can't just be applied and "unapplied" to redux at will?

Comment: Sure, that's easily done.  I've updated my answer accordingly.  Per the last question: normally middleware are fixed once you create the app, but I've seen some middlewares out there that let you dynamically modify the list of middleware at runtime (see [my list of existing middlewares](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/middleware.md#other) for some examples).

Comment: Mark, just wanted to thank you again for a great answer that I've referred back to quite a few times. I have, however, only just noticed that in this line - return storeAPI => action => next => - you have put the action and next parameters the wrong way round. I kept getting "next is undefined" until I realised how it was different from the redux website examples :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title:” Where to store Class instance for reusability in Redux?” (I know that your question was more specific)

It is not recommended to store Class instance  in Redux.

> https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions.
>
> Avoid putting non-serializable values such as Promises, Symbols,
> Maps/Sets, functions, or class instances into the Redux store state

It is explained in https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/4649

> Note that instead of class instances (that are [non- serialisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067961/what-to-use-for-data-only-objects-in-typescript-class-or-interface/41068205#41068205)) you can use [POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52453407/the-difference-between-object-and-plain-object-in-javascript), in Typescript  describe structure using [interfaces/types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652801/when-to-use-interface-and-model-in-typescript-angular/66165134#66165134)