# How to pass createAsyncThunk's result to a custom Middleware? (Connect two redux middleware)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, middleware

My custom Redux Middleware's functionality is dependent upon the result of the fulfilled action created by `createAsyncThunk`. The problem is that my custom middleware can only access the state through `getState()` and because middleware sit between an action and reducer, the new state change from `createAsyncThunk` won't be passed to the custom middleware until it reaches the reducer to update the state with the new value:

[image: Redux Cycle]

**Users Slice:**

```
// Get users
export const getUsers = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/getUsers',
  async (arg, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('users');
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  },
);

// Initial state
const initialState = {
  users: [],
  isLoading: false,
  hasError: false,
  errorMessage: '',
};

const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState,
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(getUsers.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.hasError = false;
        state.errorMessage = false;
      })
      .addCase(getUsers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.users = action.payload.users;
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.hasError = false;
      })
      .addCase(getUsers.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.errorMessage = action.payload.message;
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.hasError = true;
      })
  },
});
```

**Custom Middleware:**

```
const customMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  // Access users state
  const users = store.getState().users;

  // Main logic
  ....................................

  return next(action);
};
```

From what I understand, `createAsyncThunk` itself is a middleware that handles Asynchronous logic and just like middleware in `Express JS`, in redux too we can have a chain of middleware functions:

`Action => middleware A => middleware B => middleware C => Reducer => Store`

**What I want to do is to access the result of `middleware A` in `middleware B` and so on and establish a kind of connection between the middleware.**

Is there any way to achieve this in Redux?

**MORE DETAILS [EDIT]:**

I'm using the `middleware` to establish a private `websocket` connection with `Socket IO` and `Laravel Echo`. I need an `ID` which I get if the response from `createAsyncThunk` gets fulfilled and use that `ID` (which is required by the server) as a kind of pointer to that specific private channel:

```
echo.private(`transport.${id}`).listen(...);
```

Comment: This looks like an XY problem to me - you have a specific task that you want to do, you heard the word "middleware" somewhere and now you are trying to find a way to do this with middleware - without knowing if it's the right tool.

What are you really trying to do? All technology aside.

Comment: I'm quite sure it is the right tool, TBH. I'm using the `middleware` to establish a private `websocket` connection with `Socket IO` and `Laravel Echo`. I need an `ID` which I get if the response from `createAsyncThunk` gets fulfilled and use that `ID` (which is required by the server) as a kind of pointer to that specific private channel. (``echo.private(`transport.${id}`).listen(...);``)

Comment: And you do want this after only one certain thunk is dispatched?
Why not just `dispatch(myThunk()).unwrap().then(result => {...})`? 
You could also do that in another thunk (**not** an asyncThunk) that you dispatch instead of `myThunk`.
Writing a custom middleware is a last resort and usually you would do this for a very generic and abstracted behaviour, not only one use. Before that, look at thunks or if you really need something reactive, the `listenerMiddleware`.

Comment: @phry Thanks a lot for your answer. Let me explain the thing of I'm trying to achieve. The functionality of this part is that I `POST` a set of cargo data via `createAsyncThunk` and get a cargo transport `ID` and a receipt to that order and save them in my redux store. After getting that `ID`, I establish a `websocket` connection to a specific private channel with that `id`. This channel listens for an `event` that searches for drivers (something like Uber). Now, this is a React Native app.

Comment: @phry I'm sorry if my question seemed vague. Up until now, I never had any experience in implementing `websockets` in Redux and am not fully sure how to tackle this. According to the [documentation](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#where-should-websockets-and-other-persistent-connections-live) it seems that I should put `websocket connections` in a middleware. I also have followed Mark Erikson's examples in implementing my middleware: [example 1](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/3df1cf5abbac57820a20059287b4be58), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51845127/16590740)

Comment: It depends on "what orchestrates what". If you create the websocket connection and then you wait for one event from Redux to happen, I'd say it's not worth having a middleware for that. Generally, a websocket can also just exist as a global variable or anywhere else if you want. If that websocket should be created and you dispatch a thunk from that "creation process", just await that thunk. If that thunk fires independently, add a listener with the listener Middleware. That documentation is valid, but also very old.

Comment: Only if you have multiple actions opening multiple different websocket connections, writing your old middleware might be viable. But even then, you're often probably better off with the listener middleware.

Comment: @phry Ah I see. There is only one instance and connection which can listen to different channels based on the fired actions.

Comment: @phry Overall, thanks for your great advice Lenz! I'll check out the `createListenerMiddleware`.