# Reason: `object` ("[object Date]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma, serializable

I am using Prisma and Next.js. When I try to retrieve the content from Prisma in `getStaticProps` it does fetch the data but I can't pass it on to the main component.

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  const newsLetters = await prisma.newsLetters.findMany();
  console.log(newsLetters);

  return {
    props: {
      newsLetters: newsLetters,
    },
  };
};
```

As you can see in this image it is fetching as well as printing the content.

[image]

But when I pass I get the following error for passing it as props

```
Reason: `object` ("[object Date]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like nextJS doesn't like serializing anything but scalar types for performance reasons. You can read more in this [github issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/13209#issuecomment-633149650). Best way you can handle this is that you convert your Date objects to UNIX timestamp before returning them.

```js
// your data
let newsLetters = [
    {
        id: 'your-id',
        email: 'email@example.com',
        createdAt: new Date()
    }
];

// map the array
newsLetters.map(x => {
    x.createdAt = Math.floor(x.createdAt / 1000);
    return x;
})

// use newsLetters now
console.log(newsLetters);
```

Comment: If you don't need to edit the date later (probably not with a created at), you can convert it to a legible string instead of a unix timestamp. 
newsLetters.map(x => {
    x.createdAt = x.createdAt.toString()
    return x;
})

Answer (score 28):

If you're using **typescript**, you can't change the type of `createdAt` to a string or number, like this:

```
newsLetter.createdAt = newsLetter.createdAt.toString();
// Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
```

instead, you can use JOSN.stringfy inside JSON.parse to create a serializable object:

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  const newsLetters = await prisma.newsLetters.findMany();

  return {
     props: {
        newsLetters: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newsLetters)) // <===
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not pretty, yet pragmatic. Thank you for this workaround.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Blitz's `superjson` package](https://github.com/blitz-js/superjson) to get this working. They have instructions at https://github.com/blitz-js/superjson#using-with-nextjs:

> ### Using with Next.js
>
> The `getServerSideProps`, `getInitialProps`, and `getStaticProps` data
> hooks provided by Next.js do not allow you to transmit Javascript
> objects like Dates. It will error unless you convert Dates to strings,
> etc.
>
> Thankfully, Superjson is a perfect tool to bypass that limitation!
>
> #### Next.js SWC Plugin (experimental, v12.2 or above)
>
> Next.js SWC plugins are
> [experimental](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#swc-plugins-experimental),
> but promise a significant speedup. To use the [SuperJSON SWC
> plugin](https://github.com/blitz-js/next-superjson-plugin), install it
> and add it to your `next.config.js`:
>
> ```bash
> yarn add next-superjson-plugin
> ```
>
> ```js
> // next.config.js
> module.exports = {
>   experimental: {
>     swcPlugins: [
>       [
>         'next-superjson-plugin',
>         {
>           excluded: [],
>         },
>       ],
>     ],
>   },
> }
> ```

Comment: thanks! had to restart server a couple times before it starts working though

Answer (score 2):

According to NextJS API Docs getStaticProps return "should be a serializable object so that any props passed, could be serialized with JSON.stringify."

Under the hood they allow, boolean, number, string, and anything that passes Lodash isPlainObject test. https://lodash.com/docs/#isPlainObjectChecks.
In Lodash Documentation for this function it claims "Checks if value is a plain object, that is, an object created by the Object constructor or one with a [[Prototype]] of null."

The Following stack post discusses the difference.
[The difference between object and plain object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52453407/the-difference-between-object-and-plain-object-in-javascript)

Building on @Viktor Kynchev answer, depending on what your needing from the prop you can just convert it to a string, or number or some other type accepted by Lodash's isPlainObject.

For me I had a date Object provided via Prisma API just like OP, and I just converted it to a string like so.

```
for (const element of newsLetters) {
  element.createdAt = element.createdAt.toString()
}
```

Comment: the conversion snippet you proposed doesn't work since element.createdAt remains of type DateTime, and you can't assign a string to it

Comment: @L0g1x , its working for me, I needed it so frequently, I put it in a helper function and used it repeatedly. In what context did it not work for you? Perhaps the DateTime object you were working with was different?

Comment: @GreggoryWiley I think L0g1x is using typescript

Answer (score 1):

You probably have this in one of your model fields

```
createdAt DateTime @default(now())
```

date objects are not serializable. you could use [date-fns npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns)

```
import { formatDistance } from 'date-fns'

const newsLetters = await prisma.newsLetters.findMany();
const serializedNesLetters= newsLetters.map((newsLetter)=>({
     ...newsLetter, 
     createdAt:formatDistance(new Date(newsLetter.timestamp),new Date())
}))
```

this will return the distance between the given dates in words.

[formatDistance docs](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/formatDistance)

Answer (score 0):

Transform your Date value to some String value, like this:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const storeInfo = await getStoreInfo()

  return {
    props: {
      storeInfo: {
        ...storeInfo,
        createdAt: storeInfo?.createdAt.toISOString(),
        updatedAt: storeInfo?.updatedAt.toISOString(),
      },
    },
  }
}
```