# Best practice for Data Modeling in Ionic 3 Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, data-modeling

I am building an app with Ionic 3, Angular 4 and Firebase and I am very much confused about data modeling.
There are two ways.

1. Create a model class, declare variables and methods.
2. Create an Interface

I am not sure which approach should I take when.
An interface will be empty body but will allow optional variable but class will not.
I am just looking for a clear idea of data modeling.

Comment: This is going to be subjective, and not really an answer: but I prefer to create regular JS classes to for my data types, and then have angular services manage the data.  Interfaces are a TypeScript thing, if that matters to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use Interface and Model in TypeScript / Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652801/when-to-use-interface-and-model-in-typescript-angular2)