# Add items in array angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have following code

```
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string;
  empoloyeeID : number;
  empList: Array<{name: string, empoloyeeID: number}> = []; 
  constructor() {
  }

ngOnInit() {
  }

onEmpCreate(){
   console.log(this.name,this.empoloyeeID);
   this.empList.push.apply(this.name,this.empoloyeeID);
   this.name ="";
   this.empoloyeeID = 0;
   }
}
```

but this throwing error

> CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object

Also is there any way to create a custom class and used object list rather than defining array over here.

Thanks

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do it.

First declare a class.

```
//anyfile.ts
export class Custom
{
  name: string, 
  empoloyeeID: number
}
```

Then in your component import the class

```
import {Custom} from '../path/to/anyfile.ts'
.....
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
 name: string;
 empoloyeeID : number;
 empList: Array<Custom> = [];
 constructor() {

 }

 ngOnInit() {
 }
 onEmpCreate(){
   //console.log(this.name,this.empoloyeeID);
   let customObj = new Custom();
   customObj.name = "something";
   customObj.employeeId = 12; 
   this.empList.push(customObj);
   this.name ="";
   this.empoloyeeID = 0; 
 }
}
```

Another way would be to **interfaces** read the documentation once - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Also checkout this question, it is very interesting - [When to use Interface and Model in TypeScript / Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652801/when-to-use-interface-and-model-in-typescript-angular2)

Comment: It says Custom.ts is not a module

Comment: I think you are trying to import from Custom.ts file, where exactly did you put your Custom class?

Comment: Many thanks, restarting many times vs code worked. Very very thank your for other refrences

Answer (score 14):

Your `empList` is object type but you are trying to push strings

Try this

```
this.empList.push({this.name,this.empoloyeeID});
```

Answer (score 6):

Push object into your array. Try this:

```js
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
    name: string;
    empoloyeeID : number;
    empList: Array<{name: string, empoloyeeID: number}> = []; 
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {}
    onEmpCreate(){
        console.log(this.name,this.empoloyeeID);
        this.empList.push({ name: this.name, empoloyeeID: this.empoloyeeID });
        this.name = "";
        this.empoloyeeID = 0;
    }
}
```