# Interaction between object literal notation and object defined via constructor

Tags: typescript, interface, instance

If I define `let bar: Bar;` and assign `bar = initialFooConfig;`, is `bar` still of type Bar and an object, or is it now an object in literal notation?

As long as this assignment is possible vice versa (provided `initialFooConfig` not as const), what is the difference between `initialFooConfig` and `initialBarConfig`?

```
interface IFoo {
    code: number;
    name: string;
}

export const initialFooConfig: IFoo = {
    code: 12,
    name: "bar"
}


class Bar implements IFoo { 
    code: number;
    name: string;

    constructor(code: number, name: string) { 
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

export const initialBarConfig = new Bar(12,"bar");
```

Comment: What's "semi-instance"? The difference is that ...bar... has Bar in it's prototype chain.

Comment: @WiktorZychla _"Using simple object-literal notation"_ ... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66165134/7096274).

Comment: So it's the literal object, not the semi-instance. I doubt there's such term ever used.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript doesn't see *any* difference between IFoo and Bar, because they are *exactly same*

```
// all those are exactly the same
// they have absolutely no visible difference
// (exept the naming in hover)
type A = {a: number}
interface B {a: number}
class C {a: number = 0}
```

So you can assign them in every way possible.

In runtime their values will be whatever you see fit, you can use

```
let x: A | B | C = a{1}; // it's the same type anyways
if (x instanceof C) {} // if it's `C{a:1}`
if (Object.getPrototypeOf(x) === Object.prototype) {} // if it's `{a:1}`
```

to find if it's an object of class instance

If you want to *not* be able to assignable object to class, use

```
declare class IPrivate {
  #private;
}
const Private = Object as any as typeof IPrivate;

type A = {a: number}
interface B {a: number}
class C extends Private {a: number = 0}

let a: A = {a: 0}
let c: C = {a: 1}
//  ~ Property '#private' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'C'.(2741)
```

Comment: The question is about object instances, not about types.

Comment: @Dimava IMO this implies C is equal B no matter how constructor look like, and if `class C {a: number; constructor(a:number){this.a=a}}` equal B and `class C {a: number; constructor(b:B){this.a=b.a}}` equals B, then they are equal, they are?

Comment: @Hölderlin yes, `C`(the instance) will be the same no matter the constructor or static methods and props. `typeof C`(the constructor) will be different.