# ASP.NET Core 7 Web API : date serialization for Angular form control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, .net-7.0, asp.net-web-api-routing

In the `Person` class, `Birthday` is defined as `DateTime`.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller, I have an endpoint as follows:

```
[HttpGet("personId")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Person>> GetPerson(int personId) 
{
    var person = new Person 
                     {
                         Name = "Joe Blow",
                         Birthday = DateTime.Now
                     };
  
    return Ok(person);
}
```

When I hit my endpoint via Postman, I get this:

```
{
    "name": "Joe Blow",
    "birthday": "2023-08-07T07:37:17"
}
```

Okay, awesome. `DateTime` get serialized into this format. I believe it's called ISO 8601 but it really doesn't matter to me.

What matters is when I put it into a Reactive Forms FormControl, it is seen as a Javascript Date, not a string.

If I first replace it as a JS Date, it works:

```
person.birthday = new Date(person.birthday);
```

But I really hate doing that. What am I missing here?

The really annoying part is that in my Angular code, I explicitly state that `Person.birthday` is a `Date`:

```
export class Person {
    name: string;
    birthday: Date;
}
```

So when I use the HTTP client to get a person:

```
this.httpClient.get<Person>(url).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
  {
    next: (result: Person) => {
      console.log('Surpise: result.birthday is a string!');
    }
  }  
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Date object from json Response in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917808/how-to-get-date-object-from-json-response-in-typescript)

Comment: This has is purely related to type script. There is no way TS will understand that the string representing the date coming from the http response is a date. Look at this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917808/how-to-get-date-object-from-json-response-in-typescript

Answer (score 1):

You didn't miss anything: A Date from an API always comes back as a string (I think that can not come back as a `JavaScript` object).

Personally I solved it, By making a simple "map" in my service. In this way, your `angular` component works always on a Date `JavaScript` object

```
getData()
{
    return this.getUrl(...).pipe(map(res:any[])=>{
       res.forEach(x=>{
          x.propertyDate=new Date(x.propertyDate)
       })
       return res;
    }
    )
}

getDataId(int id)
{
    return this.getUrl(...).pipe(map(res:any)=>{
      res.propertyDate=new Date(res.propertyDate)
      return res;
    })
}

saveData(data:any)
{
     const dataSend:any={...data} //make a copy to not transform the origina data
     dataSend.propertyDate=data.propertyDate.ToString()
     return http.post(....,dataSend)
}
```

Comment: That is essentially what I am doing, although I'm not super happy with it.  Too many different dates in too many different model classes.  Now if there were some way to do this generically, using some type of typescript reflection, so that any property marked as a Date would get this treatment, that would be pretty cool.

Comment: @FunkMonkey33, please, if you find another way, tell me (I'm not very happy to do it too)

Comment: @FunkMonkey33, this [link](https://dev.to/bwca/typed-dates-conversion-with-typescript-49n7) I just googled it's related to the question (but it's really not a great advance)