# Java 8 Backend Joda DateTime convert to JavaScript Date

Tags: javascript, java, date, jodatime

I need the following Javascript- object in the frontend. Therefore I made a class with the same properties in the backend. My problem now is the **startAt** date. I don't know which type I should use in backend (JodaTime DateTime is different to javascript Date- object) so that I do not have to convert this **startsAt** property in the frontend. Is there any possibility or do I have to convert this object in frontend in that way to convert Joda DateTime to Javascript Date object?

```
{
title: 'My testevent',
startsAt: new Date(2016,7,19,9),
allDay: false,
type: 'SCHEDULE_PRESENCE',
institutionId: '123',
institutionName: 'Zur Weinstrasse',
userId: '321',
userName: 'Hannes Weninger',
userRole: 'USER-ROLE',
color: calendarConfig.colorTypes.warning
}
```

Comment: Why use Joda Time with Java 8 when you have JSR 310? Also, on the JS end, do you know the time zone?

Comment: How does your data get from the backend to the frontend? How is it serialized?

Comment: I send JSON from backend to frontend by REST- Services.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON to receive a Date object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511705/how-to-parse-json-to-receive-a-date-object-in-javascript)