# Pass list of values from Code-Behind to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I currently have a `list` of dates in my code-behind, I'd like to pass the `list` to a variable in `javascript` without the use of `hiddenfield`

For instance,

Aspx.cs:

```
List < DateTime > blockedDate = new List < DateTime > ();

foreach(DataRow blockedRow in phBLL.getAllPH(DateTime.Now.Year).Tables[0].Rows) 
{
   blockedDate.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(blockedRow["date1"]));
}
```

Aspx:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     var arrayOfDates = ""    
});
```

What I've tried

Aspx.cs:

```
public static List < DateTime > blockedDate = new List < DateTime > ();

[WebMethod]
public static List < DateTime > blockDates() 
{
  foreach(DataRow blockedRow in phBLL.getAllPH(DateTime.Now.Year).Tables[0].Rows) {
  blockedDate.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(blockedRow["date1"]));
 }

 return blockedDate;
}
```

Javascript:

```
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "CreateClass.aspx/blockDates",
     data: null,
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     dataType: 'json',
     error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
     },
     success: function(result) {
         for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
             var dates = [new Date(parseInt(result.d[i].substr(6)))];
             console.log(dates);
         }
     }
 });
```

I am trying to get the `result` and place into an Array. So it'd end up something like this

**an array of dates**

```
var array = ["2016/11/14", "2016/11/15", "2016/11/16"];
```

Comment: Create a webmethod which contain your code behind logic and call it using ajax.

Comment: or print serialized json into page as value of the variable. Both approaches are very easy to research

Comment: @Div I tried, but I kept getting something like `[Object] object` or `\Date(random numbers)/`

Comment: @Arane: Add that code in the question.

Comment: @Div Posted! really do need help on this, thanks..

Comment: @Arane: Yeah, you get something like `\Date(random numbers)/` because you cannot parse json to  date directly, read [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx) and also refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511705/how-to-parse-json-to-receive-a-date-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @Div Do you know how to put the result into an array like for instance like this `var array = ["2016/11/14", "2016/11/15", "2016/11/16"];`??

Comment: @Arane: Do you know about [`JavaScript Array push() Method`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) ?

Comment: @Div Managed to do it, at long last haha... thank you so much for the guidance and help! Much appreciated!!

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, Create a `[WebMethod]` which contain your code behind logic and call it using ajax.

Now, you will get data on ajax success, and just push your data to array `arrayOfDates` using [`JavaScript Array push() Method`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Merci Beaucoup!