# How to format google chart x axis in DateTime format from C#

Tags: c#, charts, asp.net-mvc-5, google-visualization

I'm developing a web site in MVC 5 and I'm using google chart to display some chart for my data. I'm using the line chart for a data which have a value and a date. Something like the follow:

```
class ChartData
{
  public double Value { get; set; }
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
};
```

In my controller I have a request handler to generate the data for the chart:

```
    public JsonResult GenerateChartData(int id)
    {
        List<ChartData> list = new List<ChartData>();
        // some code to populate the list
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Everything works fine except that the X axis which should show the date time sequence is formatted in the wrong way. The looks like absolute time not in readable date format.

[see the chart output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACIls.png)

thanks for any answer

Comment: What do you mean by 'the X axis that should show the time of the sequence is formatted the wrong way' ? Do you have an example ?

Comment: I'd like to see on the hAxis something like: 2017-05-16 11:00, 2017-05-16 11:01 and so on. Now I see just the ticks of the UT format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. Reading this article made everything clear

[How to parse JSON to receive a Date object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511705/how-to-parse-json-to-receive-a-date-object-in-javascript)

I modified the java script code inside my page in the following way:

```
    var dataArray = [
    ['Date', 'Value']
    ];
    $.each(jsondata, function (i, item) {
        var d = new Date(parseInt(item.Instant.substr(6)));
        dataArray.push([d, item.Value]);
    });
```

Now it works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

google charts will [accept dates in a couple ways](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes),

which depend on how the data table, used to draw the chart, is loaded...

**1)**

if you're using one of the following methods to load the data table...

`addRow()`, `addRows()`, `arrayToDataTable()`

the date will need to be a javascript date object,
created using the `new` keyword,
any [valid constructor will work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, month[, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

**2)**

if using json to [load the data table directly](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

the following [string format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#datestring) can be used...

which needs to be a string value (wrapped in quotes), *without* the `new` keyword...

`"Date(Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds)"`

where `Month` is zero-based

`"Date(2017, 4, 16)"  // <-- 5/16/2017`

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to load the data inside a java script. But in my case the data are generate in json format by a request to the controller. I post the code of my page

```
@model BDF.RemoteData.Data.TagData
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Chart";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>[[[Grafico]]]</h2>

<input type="hidden" id="idInput" data-value="@ViewBag.id" />
<input type="hidden" id="idSystem" data-value="@ViewBag.system" />
<input type="hidden" id="idStart" data-value="@ViewBag.start" />
<input type="hidden" id="idEnd" data-value="@ViewBag.end" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1",
{
    packages: ["corechart"]
});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart()
{
var id = $("#idInput").data("value");
var system = $("#idSystem").data("value");
var start = $("#idStart").data("value");
var end = $("#idEnd").data("value");

$.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '@Url.Action("GenerateChartData")',
    data:
        {
            id: id,
            system: system,
            start: start,
            end: end
        },
        type: "GET",
        error: function (xhr, status, error)
        {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            toastr.error(err.message);
        },
        beforeSend: function ()
        {
        },
        success: function (data)
        {
            HistDashboardChart(data);
            return false;
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error)
        {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            toastr.error(err.message);
        },
        complete: function ()
        {
        }
    });
    return false;
}
//This function is used to bind the user data to chart
function HistDashboardChart(data)
{
    $("#Data_Chart").show();
    var dataArray = [
    ['Date', 'Value']
    ];
    $.each(data, function (i, item)
    {
        dataArray.push([item.Date, item.Value]);
    });
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
    var options = {
        legend:
        {
            position: 'bottom',
            textStyle:
            {
                color: '#f5f5f5'
            }
        },
        colors: ['#34A853', 'ff6600', '#FBBC05'],
        backgroundColor: '#454545',
        hAxis:
        {
            title: 'Time',
            titleTextStyle:
            {
                italic: false,
                color: '#00BBF1',
                fontSize: '20'
            },
            textStyle:
            {
                color: '#f5f5f5'
            }
        },
        vAxis:
        {
            baselineColor: '#f5f5f5',
            title: 'Values',
            titleTextStyle:
            {
                color: '#00BBF1',
                italic: false,
                fontSize: '20'
            },
            textStyle:
            {
                color: '#f5f5f5'
            },
            viewWindow:
            {
                min: 0,
                format: 'long'
            }
        },
        curveType: 'function',
    };
    var chart = new     google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('Data_Chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    return false;
};
</script>  

<div id="Data_Chart" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"> </div>
```

As you can see the job id done by the request url: '@Url.Action("GenerateChartData")'
Then the returned data are pushed into an array the the code

```
    var dataArray = [
    ['Date', 'Value']
    ];
    $.each(data, function (i, item)
    {
        dataArray.push([item.Date, item.Value]);
    });
```

In this case I'm assuming that item.Date is already in a datetime format but maybe I have to format it in a special way.

Comment: in the last snippet above, what is the value of `item.Date`? please share the result of --> `console.log(item.Date);`

Answer (score 0):

The output of the console.log(item.Date) is the following:

```
/Date(1494937128000)/
/Date(1494937133000)/
/Date(1494937138000)/
/Date(1494937143000)/
/Date(1494937148000)/
/Date(1494937153000)/
/Date(1494937158000)/
/Date(1494937163000)/
```

Which looks strange I think, doesn't it?

Comment: I think the issue is the leading and final / symbol. Maybe I have to format in some specific way the json serialization of the Date from my model calss