# Why expired in local storage javascript failed?

Tags: javascript, date, time, local-storage

My code to set local storage like this :

```
var now = new Date();
now.setHours(now.getHours() + 1);
var cacheData = {data: data, expired: now}
localStorage.setItem('storedData', JSON.stringify(cacheData))
```

My code to check expired or no like this :

```
var object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storedData")),
    expired = object.expired,
    now = new Date()

if(now > expired) {
    console.log('cache dihapus')
    localStorage.removeItem("storedData");
}
```

After 1 hour, I run the script, but the local storage not remodev

Why it not removed?

The result of console.log(now) and console.log(expired) like this :

> Wed Aug 09 2017 17:41:13 GMT+0700 (Russia TZ 6 Standard Time)
>
> 2017-08-09T10:29:21.933Z

Seems the format different. Maybe its a problem there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON to receive a Date object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511705/how-to-parse-json-to-receive-a-date-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expired is in JSON format (for Date). Better, you convert 'now' to the same format by using,

```
now = new Date()
now = now.toJSON()
```

You can compare 'now' and 'expired' by using > or < or ==, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to compare with `> < =` you should run it on the `getTime()` of a Date object.

So construct two dates with the strings you have and then compare them as such:
`if(now.getTime() > expired.getTime())`

I'm afraid at the moment you are comparing a String with a Date object.

Answer (score 0):

JSON does not support `Date` objects, so when you `JSON.stringify` your data to put it into LocalStorage, the dates get flattened into strings.

To turn them back into proper `Date` objects, pass them to the `Date` constructor (e.g. `new Date(yourString);`), or use a library like Moment.js.