# Convert this timestamp to normal date

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

"usage_timestamp": [13308678945000000]

I have this timestamp in my json file.
How to convert this timestamp to normal date use Node js?

As I understand it, this is not exactly a unix timestamp. What is shown during normal conversion does not look like the truth

Comment: "date in JSON" is not a thing: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately you have to write code to de-serialize your dates in whatever language you're loading the JSON into

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Add tag for programming language.

Comment: see [How to parse JSON to receive a Date object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511705/how-to-parse-json-to-receive-a-date-object-in-javascript) for date specific JSON.parse reviver discussion

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp you provided looks like a **Unix timestamp** in **microseconds**. To convert it to a normal date in Node.js, you can use the Date constructor and the `getTime()` method.

you can convert the **timestamp** to a **normal date** in Node.js:

```
const timestamp = 13308678945000000;
const date = new Date(timestamp / 1000);
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

`timestamp` variable is divided by `1000` to convert it from `microseconds` to seconds. **Date** constructor is then used to create a `new Date` object from the `timestamp`. `toISOString()` method is used to convert the Date object to an `ISO string`.

**Output:**
`2012-03-04T05:04:55.000Z`

`2012-03-04T05:04:55.000Z` - This string represents the date and time in (UTC). If you want to display the date and time in a different time zone, you can use a library like **moment-timezone** to convert the date to the desired time zone.

Thank you.

Comment: don't recommend outdated packages. see [Moment: Project Status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) for their own assessment of why one might consider more modern libraries including their own statement *'...we would like to discourage Moment from being used in new projects going forward.'*