# Javascript - match Regex for this date represenation

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I write a proper regex for:

```
/Date(1518238800000)/ - matches

jdsjdsj - no match

2017/03/12 - no match

12 - no match

Date() - no match

/Date(1218238800000)/ - matches
```

What I have so far is:

```
var res = str.match(/Date(\d*)/g);
```

How can I amend the regex to work?

Comment: JSON does not have a date object.

Comment: edited, my bad!

Comment: There is no "JSON date" either. How is this related to JSON at all?

Comment: You should escape parentheses `Date\(\d+\)`

Comment: I cannot store a Date Object as a json literal, only '/Date(XXXXXXX)/

Comment: `JSON.stringify({date:new Date()})` produces something like `{"date":"2018-03-04T17:27:00.609Z"}`. That is usually how you use dates within JSON.

Comment: Do you want to match or match+capture?

Comment: To people who do not like the word JSON, then read "serializer"

Comment: @str this representation is common in ASP.NET MVC. If you have not heard about it does not mean it does not exist.

Comment: @SalmanA JSON is language-agnostic and this question is tagged with JavaScript.

Comment: @str If OP posts the complete string, perhaps you will be happy. It is likely ASP.NET JSON which serializes DateTime to the following format `"/Date(1251877601000)/".`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367899/how-to-parse-asp-net-json-date-format-with-gwt

Comment: @mplungjan It is ASP.NET Json

Comment: @BDillan I know now after having to defend OPs use of the word JSON ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your string is a bit from a .NET serializer as mentioned here

[How to parse ASP.NET JSON Date format with GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367899/how-to-parse-asp-net-json-date-format-with-gwt)

and

[How to parse JSON to receive a Date object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511705/how-to-parse-json-to-receive-a-date-object-in-javascript)

One of the answers have a reviver function you may want to use.

If not then the regex will need to have the parenthesis escaped:

```js
var str = '{ "date": "/Date(1218238800000)/" }'
var re = /Date\((\d*)\)/g // escaping the () from the date and capture the number
res = re.exec(str);

console.log(res[1])
```

More dates and create date object:

```js
var str = '{ "date1": "/Date(1218238800000)/", "date2": "/Date(1218248800000)/" }'
var re = /Date\((\d*)\)/g // escaping the () from the date and capture the number

while (res = re.exec(str)) {
  var date = +res[1]; // convert
  console.log(new Date(date)) 
}
```

Comment: But that is not JSON.

Comment: But likely what OP meant

Comment: We should not encourage things like this. Either the terminology or the use of 'JSON' is completely wrong.

Comment: @str Many names for such things. Likely the output of .NET https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511705/how-to-parse-json-to-receive-a-date-object-in-javascript

Comment: But it is still not valid JSON. `{ "date": "Date(1218238800000)" }` would be though.

Comment: OP is receiving something like this `{"date":"\/Date(1518238800000)\/"}` (which is valid JSON)... you might want to tweak your answer a little.

Comment: @SalmanA Tweaked

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the special characters like this:

```js
let regex = /\/Date\(\d+\)\//g;
console.log(regex.test("/Date(123455)/"), //true
  regex.test("Date()"), //false
  regex.test("afdjkh"), //false
  regex.test("/Date(38457843)/")) //true
```